Blender 4.1 - Gas Domain Not Adapting to all flow objects
I have a gas domain set to smoke with two flow objects.
One flow object (ground smoke) stays near the ground; it is emulating the large volume burst of smoke (water vapor, etc) that comes from a rocket.
The second flow object (rocket smoke) is parented to a rocket model which is animated to rise on the Z axis.
My issue is that the domain, which is set to adaptive, is not adapting to the rocket smoke flow object as it rises. It grows outward for the ground smoke, but not upwards.
The end result is that I have a fantastic looking ground burst, but no smoke coming from the end of the rocket as it rises.
I tried turning off adaptive domain and making the domain the correct z scale, but the performance hit it takes when baking is massive.
Has anyone else had experience with this, and may be able to offer a solution that lets me use adaptive domain while recognizing the and adapting to both flow objects? Or do I just need to suck it up and let it bake using the domain scaled to both objects in a static state?
Thank in advance for any suggestions!

It would be easier to bake 2 simulations and domains (otherwise lot of empty space). Did you try playing with the threshold value of the adaptive domain ? As you describe it, it seems the rocket smoke isnt dense enough

Have you set the Flow Behavior on the rocket to Inflow or is it the default Geometry? The latter only initializes smoke on the first simulation frame. Using two domains like @Lutzi suggests can help with slightly quicker baking and if you want to use different domain settings or even different smoke materials on ground smoke and rocket. But then you have to use different folders for the caches and put the flow objects in different collections and use the Collections in the domain settings. Downside is, the two smoke simulations do not interact with each other.

The smoke for both the ground smoke and rocket smoke flow objects is very dense; the ground smoke simulation is actually perfect, I even added wind for movement before it dissipates and it looks beautiful. The issue was that the domain was not growing on the Z axis, so the rocket smoke terminated as it left the domain (because it was parented to the rising rocket). Also, both flow objects are set to inflow or I would get no visible smoke to speak of. I found the solution was to scale the domain on the Z to make sure the original size was large enough to encapsulate both flow objects.

Adding another comment; I appreciate your suggestions very much. Not wild about the two domains idea, but may have to go that route because the rocket smoke looks goofy with the ground smoke settings. Over and over again I am leas than thrilled with Mantaflow; it is far too buggy and temperamental to get consistently good results.
